# Barbados via JFK - Transit on Media Visa

Tags: visas, transit, jfk, barbados

I'm travelling to Barbados via JFK, I have a US Media Visa - will my Media Visa allow me transit through US or will I require a different visa (C1/B1)?

Answer (score 3):

[Visas for Members of the Foreign Media, Press, and Radio](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/employment/visas-members-foreign-media-press-radio.html)

> Activities in the United States while on a media (I) visa must be for
>   a media organization having its home office in a foreign country.
>   Activities in the United States must be informational in nature and
>   generally associated with the news gathering process and reporting on
>   current event

I believe you need a visitor or transit visa because your plans (transit) do not fit the requirements.

Comment: However, non-transit visas are inherently superior to transit visas

Comment: @Coke but for example a G-4 visa is not valid for transit (or any travel) when the travel is personal in nature.  It's really not clear from the statutory definition of the media category how it would apply to transit.

Comment: Anecdotally I have heard that CBP allows transits on nonimmigrant visas (other than G for non-official travel). But I can't point you to any document that says this explicitly. I have also heard that foreign media _must_ enter the US on their I visa regardless of their purpose of travel.